# How to create lists from csv files and cast columns to ints and floats

Tags: python, csv

This is the function I have now for reading two different CSV files:

```
def readCSVfile(str1):
    if str1 == 'small':
        with open('small.csv', 'r+') as f:
            read_small = csv.reader(f)
            for row in read_small:
                return read_small
    elif str1 == 'big':
        with open('big.csv', 'r+') as f:
                read_big = csv.reader(f)
                for row in read_big:
                    return read_big    
    else:
        print "File not found"
```

The small file printed looks like this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting string to int and float use `int()` and `float()` methods respectively. Demo could look like this:

```
lst = ['1', '1', '2.2', '1.3', '9.6']
[int(x) if "." not in x else float(x) for x in lst]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2.2, 1.3, 9.6]
```

Possible modification of your code:

```
def readCSVfile(str1):
    if str1 == 'small':
        with open('small.csv', 'r+') as f:
            read_small = csv.reader(f)
            next(read_small) # skip header
            modified_data = []
            for row in read_small:
                temp = [[int(x) if "." not in x else float(x) for x in row] # convert string elements to int and float elements
                modified_data.append(temp)
            return modified_data
    # ...
```

P.s. More robust way to convert string to int or float is showed in simple example below:

```
def num(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return float(s)
```

For using it modify string with temp:

```
temp = [num(x) for x in row]
```

You can easily modify function `num()` to work in case of dirty data, like *"1."* or something else.

Comment: I need to write something that works for any file inserted in the program that is structured in the same way as my example above

Comment: A potential issue with this might be that if the first two columns (which are meant to be `int`s) contain a `.` then it'll be silently converted to a `float` - which may or may not be desired behaviour.

Comment: @Gregg you could also be explicit: `temp = [t(v) for t, v in zip((int, int, float, float, float), row)]`

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to install Pandas, it will do exactly what you expect:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
>>> data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 12 entries, 0 to 11
Data columns (total 5 columns):
site          12 non-null int64
experiment    12 non-null int64
length        12 non-null float64
width         12 non-null float64
height        12 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(2)
memory usage: 576.0 bytes
>>> print(data)
    site  experiment  length  width  height
0      1           1     2.2    1.3     9.6
1      1           2     2.1    2.2     7.6
2      1           3     2.7    1.5     2.2
3      2           1     3.0    4.5     1.5
4      2           2     3.1    3.1     4.0
5      2           3     2.5    2.8     3.0
6      3           1     1.9    1.8     4.5
7      3           2     1.1    0.5     2.3
8      3           3     3.5    2.0     7.5
9      4           1     2.9    2.7     3.2
10     4           2     4.5    4.8     6.5
11     4           3     1.2    1.8     2.7
```

Comment: Interesting, i will see if this also works with the calculations i need to do.